# Importing a service in python defined by others

Tags: python, path, ros-kinetic, service, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am stuck in something that should be pretty easy... I have a service called "set_odometry", which I can use doing rosservice from the bash. This service is installed from apt-get so I don't have the code for it, I guess it is written in C++ but it shares the .srv file in /opt/kinetic/share/PATH_TO_SERVICE/set_odometry.srv

Now, I want to use it from my python based node. Of course, I can simply do a rosservice call from the script, but I think this is not the way to proceed. I am trying to use it as if it was a service that I defined, this means using rospy.ServiceProxy.
However, I can not import the .srv in my python code.
I have tried several ways to do

```
from set_odometry.srv import *
```

It always answers no module named set_odometry.
I have included /opt/kinetic/share/PATH_TO_SERVICE/ in my python path, I have added **init**.py in the folder... nothing has worked so far.
I think this should be something easy and standard to do, I mean, using another one's service from my code, but I am unable to do it.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352105/importing-a-service-in-python-defined-by-others/) by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2020-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm not sure about your definition of the service file. A quick google search lead me to https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/robotnik_msgs/blob/master/srv/set_odometry.srv which provides a service definition and maybe was released for kinetic, so the path would be /opt/ros/kinetic/….

My assumption is you confused the package name with the service name here. Like in the Tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) you have to `from package_name.srv import *`, so in your case `from robotnik_msgs.srv import *` (even though in general just import the things you need, so `SetOdometry` and `SetOdometryRequest` in this case)

If the command line command `rossrv show robotnik_msgs/SetOdometry` works, then the import statement of your python script should work as well.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [ipa-jba](https://answers.ros.org/users/3541/ipa-jba/) with karma: 153 on 2020-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bernat Gaston](https://answers.ros.org/users/44457/bernat-gaston/) on 2020-05-12**:
Thanks! it worked. Ok I understand the error that I was doing. Thank you so much